# Prove that $\forall(A,B) \in \mathcal{P}(U) × \mathcal{P}(U), f(A, B) = f(B, A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove that $\forall(A,B) \in \mathcal{P}(U) × \mathcal{P}(U), f(A, B) = f(B, A)$.

How do I write in predicate logic(mathematical symbols) that $f(A, B) = A \cap B$ for all $(A, B) \in \mathcal{P}(U) × \mathcal{P}(U)$ is surjective (onto)? Prove or disprove this statment.

Comment: I can't figure out what statement you want to prove or disprove. You want to prove (or disprove) that $f(A,B)=f(B,A)$ or that $f(A,B)=A\cap B$ or that $f$ is surjective? Anyway, you won't be able to prove anything very interesting about your function $f$ with no definition and no hypotheses.

Comment: First, I want to prove the above statement($f(A,B)=f(B,A)$).
Then I want to write the second statemen in predicate logic and prove or disprove it(whatever's true).

Comment: I don't see how you can hope to prove $f(A,B)=f(B,A)$ for an ***undefined*** function $f,$ with no hypotheses on $f.$ For instance, if $U$ is a nonempty set, the function $f(A,B)=A$ is a counterexample. Perhaps you know something else about the function $f$ that you haven't bothered to tell us?